# Select Most Recent Distinct Customer Row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that stores customer sales date like this:

```
|CustomerId|SalesDate |Product|Price|
|1         |2015-01-01|A      | 5.00|
|1         |2015-02-01|A      |10.00|
|1         |2015-03-01|B      | 7.00|
|2         |2015-01-15|A      | 9.00|
```

I'd like to select a single row for each customer who has purchased product A. If a customer has purchased product A more than once, I'd like to only see the most recent purchase.

This is the desired output:

```
|CustomerId|SalesDate |Product|Price|
|1         |2015-02-01|A      |10.00|
|2         |2015-01-15|A      | 9.00|
```

I've tried different versions of a group by/having queries like this:

```
SELECT CustomerId, SalesDate, Product, Price
FROM Sales
WHERE Product = 'A'
GROUP BY CustomerId
HAVING MAX(SalesDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab the max of sales date in the select statement.

```
select customerid, max(salesdate) as salesdate, 'A'
from sales
where product = 'A'
group by customerid
```

with new requirements

```
select customerid, maxsalesdate, Product, Price
from sales
join (select customerid, max(salesdate) as maxsalesdate
      from sales
      where product = 'A'
      group by customerid) as sub on 
        sub.customerid = sales.customerid and 
        sub.maxsalesdate = sales.salesdate
where product = 'A'
```

Comment: You need to add the product to the group by clause as well...

    Group By customerid, product

Comment: @toconn - or make it constant (since it is)

Comment: This loses the price that they paid at that date.

Comment: @DeadZone - True, that requirement was added after I answered the question

Comment: @DeadZone - that better?

Answer (score 2):

Do this using a `join` and aggregation:

```
select s.*
from sales s join
     (select customerid, max(salesdate) as salesdate
      from sales s
      where product = 'A'
      group by customerid
     ) cs
     on s.customerid = cs.customerid and s.salesdate = cs.salesdate
where s.product = 'A';
```

The aggregation gets the maximum sales date for each customer.  The `join` selects the row that matches that information.

Comment: I don't think you need the main where clause if it is in the inner join's sub-query.  Is there ever a case where it would matter?

Comment: @Hogan . . . Yes.  The user could have multiple sales on the most recent date for product A.  The OP appears to only want information about the product A entry.